# Proof that biconditional implication is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, logic, propositional-calculus

The definition of an equivalence relation is that of a binary relation between distinct elements of a set. Partial orders have a similar definition.

*Seeing as this could include things like the set of all people, as well as standard sets of numbers, could an equivalence relation, and by extension, a partial order, be constructed over the set of Boolean statements (such as 'It will rain tomorrow') which have true or false values?*

I have conjectured and attempted to prove that biconditional implication $\leftrightarrow$ is an equivalence relation.

Proof: Let $p, q, r$ be propositions with value true or false.

**Claim 1: $\leftrightarrow$ is reflexive.** If $p$ is a proposition with value true or false, $\neg p \lor p$ is a tautology, but by the law of material implication $\neg p \lor p \equiv p \to p$. So $p \to p$ together with itself gives $p \leftrightarrow p$ and $\leftrightarrow$ is reflexive.

**Claim 2: $\leftrightarrow$ is symmetric.** Suppose $p \leftrightarrow q$. Then by definition, $p \to q \land q \to p$. The commutative law gives $q \to p \land p \to q \equiv q \leftrightarrow p$ and hence $\leftrightarrow$ is symmetric.

**Claim 3: $\leftrightarrow$ is transitive.** Suppose $p \leftrightarrow q \land q \leftrightarrow r$. Using definitions, the associative & commutative laws and transitivity of $\to$ we have $$(p \to q \land q \to p) \land (q \to r \land r \to q)$$
$$\equiv (p \to q \land q \to r) \land (r \to q \land q \to p)$$
$$\equiv (p \to r) \land (r \to p)$$
$$\equiv p \leftrightarrow r$$

and so $\leftrightarrow$ is transitive.

By proof of claims 1, 2 and 3, $\leftrightarrow$ is an equivalence relation.

Comment: Note that partial orders are usually required to be _antisymmetric_. Relations that are reflexive and transitive but possibly not antisymmetric are often called [preorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preorder).

Comment: In your proof of claim 3, you should be careful that $(p \to q) \land (q \to r)$ does imply $p \to r$ but is not actually equivalent to $p \to r$ (check it with $p$ false, $q$ true and $r$ false).

Answer (score 3):

To be sure, biconditional implication is an equivalence relation.

How to prove that most directly depends on your official definition of the biconditional. So there's no "right" answer here. You give *one* line of argument which works given enough background apparatus.

But of course, if you define biconditional implication semantically by the standard truth-table, then reflexivity and symmetry can be trivially read off the truth-table, and the most direct proof of transitivity is by an eight-line brute force calculation. If you define the biconditional proof-theoretically by its natural deduction rules, then the most direct proof that it is an equivalence relation is by three trivial natural deduction proofs.